# How to executeScript on all frames of a page as they load (i.e. not using document_idle)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

My WebExtension (for Firefox, in this case) modifies pages by executing a script on them. I need the script to work on the page and all its frames, and I need it to happen as soon as possible when the page/frame is created (i.e. while things in the page are still loading).

There are two options I see, both of which can't achieve this:

1. Call `browser.tabs.executeScript()` to inject the script with `runAt: "document_start"` and `allFrames: false`. On the executed content script itself, try to modify all frames of the window. This is not possible for frames whose content comes from another domain, due to cross domain policies.
2. Call `browser.tabs.executeScript()` with `allFrames: true`. The script will be injected into all frames, but if a frame takes longer to load, using `runAt: "document_start"` will only execute on the main document and not the frame. Using `"document_idle"` works well but takes a long time to work.

I've also tried calling `executeScript` with `runAt: "document_start"` and `allFrames: false`, followed by another call with `runAt: "document_idle"` and `allFrames: true`. This would be middle ground, letting the main document work immediately (most pages) but delaying frames a bit. However, the executed script will get injected twice in the main page and cause errors.

None of these let me execute the script on all frames as they load. How can I do this?

I suspect a more cumbersome solution is needed and I'd appreciate it if you have ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more fine-grained control over injecting your scripts. I have an extension with a `webNavigation.onCompleted` listener that fires when the page is fully loaded.

```
browser.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details){
  // don't inject into the main frame (id = 0)
  if(details.frameId != 0) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {file: "js/contentScript.js", frameId: details.frameId});
  }
});
```

This requires the `webNavigation` permission in manifests.json

Maybe that would work along with your first script injected into the main frame at `document_start`.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you very much for the answer. That works! Glorious! ;)

I'd like to add a few things to your example, if you don't mind. :)

1. You need to add `frameId: details.frameId` to the object passed to executeScript, otherwise it will still try to execute on the main page and not the frame. But adding that to your example works nicely.

2. In my case I want things to work as soon as possible, so using onDOMContentLoaded instead of onCompleted is preferred.

Cheers! It's unfortunate that I'll need the extra permission just for this, but it's still the only option that works. :)

Comment: Great, glad it works for you! I've updated my answer to include `frameId: details.frameId`, that wasn't necessary for my use case but it certainly is for yours.